# Infinite Loop BootStrap.groovy while saving data grails 2.1.1

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have the following code in the init closure of BootStrap.groovy

```
private def setupDefaultAdmin = {

        log.info "Adding default user to system"

        // create the super user/admin account

        if (SentryUser.findAllByUsername("test@test.org") == null) {
        def admin = new SentryUser(username: "test@test.org",password: 'password',
                enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)

        admin = new SentryUser(username: "admin@test.org",password: 'password',
                enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
        }

    }
```

When I deploy this application to the JBOSS container version 7.1 I keep getting in to infinite loop when deploying. My DB config is as follows

```
production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if you remove the bootstrap? The deploy works?

Comment: The issue was found for some reasons jboss doesn't like         grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true . I removed it from the production setting and the error is gone. I found this out after I commented out the method in bootstrap. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Note that Grails findAll* dynamic finders never return null. They always return an ArrayList which may be empty. So `if (SentryUser.findAllByUsername("test@test.org") == null) {` should be `if (!SentryUser.findAllByUsername("test@test.org")) {` or even better, `if (!SentryUser.countByUsername("test@test.org")) {`

Comment: I had the same (!SentryUser.findAllByUsername("test@test.org")) before. Since I couldn't find the reason of the infinite loop I had changed it to comparing it to null, thinking that was causing it to go inside the if statement and executing the save but that was not the cause. Thanks for the pointer though

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to         grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true

so please keep it mind that if you see any weirdness on JBOSS and have this setting turned on in prod, it may cause issues.